# Verify that if some vectors are removed from a linearly independent list(set), the remaining list(set) is also linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I found this in Axler's Linear Algebra done right. Although this seems trivial, I can't find a rigorous way to prove it.

Comment: If the reduced list is linearly dependent then you can write one element as a linear combination of the others. But this proves that the original set is linearly dependent. Contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition. We have $k_1\alpha_1+k_2\alpha_2+\cdots+k_m\alpha_m=0 \Rightarrow k_1=k_2=\cdots=k_m$

Take some vectors out of the set.We got {$a_{i_j}$}

If the vectors of the new set are linearly dependent.
We can work out the values of $k_{i_j}$.
When other $k=0$,we can prove {$\alpha_i$} is linearly dependent,which leads into a paradox.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the reduced vector list is linearly dependent, i.e., there exist coefficients, not all zero, such that a linear combination of the reduced vector list would equal zero. For typing convenience, I'll assume WLOG that we take out $v_n$ (taking any amount of arbitary vectors work the same way), so
$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}v_{n-1}=0$$

Where not all $a_j$'s $(j=1,2,\cdots,n-1)$ equals to $0$. Subbing this combination equation into the unreduced combination equation $$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots++a_nv_{n-1}+a_nv_{n}=0$$
Generally, letting all the coefficients in front of the vectors that had been thrown away be $0$ (in this case, let $a_n=0$) would create a new set of coefficients that satisfies:

$1$. Not all zero

$2$.The linear combination equals to zero

This means the unreduced vector list is linearly dependent, which leads to a contradiction.